# Creating Subtotals - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below data set, which is reporting employee hours for each day, and each day has a week number (1 or 2) as running for two weeks.

```
    SiteId  SiteName  EmployeeId  FirstName   SurName  Date        WorkedHours  WorkedMinutes  WeekNo
    4       Test      7           Steve       Stone    2014-03-01  4.5          270              1
    4       Test      7           Steve       Stone    2014-03-02  9            540              1
    4       Test      7           Steve       Stone    2014-03-03  4.5          270              1
    4       Test      7           Steve       Stone    2014-03-08  4.5          270              2
    4       Test      7           Steve       Stone    2014-03-09  9            540              2
    4       Test      7           Steve       Stone    2014-03-10  4.5          270              2
```

I would like to add a sub total of workedhours and workedminutes for each employee for each week.  So the desired outcome would have a row at the end of each section of weeks for the sub total, which would give a total for week 1 and then again for week 2

Comment: Look into this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollup was the best way forward 
[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or above you should take a look at `GROUPING SETS`. They are much faster than `Rollup`. Its an awesome feature to do such tasks.

I recently implemented similar logic

```
select EmpId, Year, FaciLeaveType, Month, DateValue , Sum(Leaves)
FROM EmplLeave
GROUP BY 
GROUPING SETS(
                  ( EmpId,Year,FaciLeaveType,Month,DateValue )
                 ,( EmpId,Year,FaciLeaveType,Month )
                 ,( EmpId,Year,FaciLeaveType )
      )
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx